# Why isn't my signal handler being called?

Tags: c, unix, posix, signals

Im working on a assignment which uses signals to transfer a binary message between two processes, with the goal of learning about signals (it is a strange use indeed).

In my program, the two processes communicate a code, and then one transfers a message to the other. SIGUSR1 represents 0, SIGUSR2 represents 1. The idea is that the process sending the message will use the kill function with whichever SIGUSR to get the message across, and the receiving process will have a signal handler to interpret the codes.

So here is the problem. 
I have the sender start up. it sleeps while it waits for the code to be sent.
The reciever sends two SIGINT's to signify the 'password', using `pidof(8)` to find the pid of the sender.

Once the sender's signal handler has read these signals, recognizes it is the proper password, it then proceeds to send the message.

The reciever has now gone through a few functions, and is sleeping every second waiting for each bit to be passed via an interrupt. The problem is, this never happens.

I have set it up such that the sender is sending a bit(0 in this case) like so:

```
kill(washingtonPID,SIGUSR1);
```

where washingtonPID is the PID of the receiver, and I have verified this is the correct PID.

the receiver's handler is hooked up like so:

```
//IN MAIN
    signal(SIGINT,bitReceiver);
    signal(SIGUSR1,bitReceiver);
    signal(SIGUSR2,bitReceiver);
//OUTSIDE MAIN

    void bitReceiver(int signum)
{
    if(signum == SIGUSR1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"SIGUSR1 - 0");
        bit = 0;
    }
    else if (signum == SIGUSR2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"SIGUSR2 - 1");
        bit = 1;
    }
    else //sigint
    raise(SIGINT);

    return;
}
```

where bit is a global variable. it is initially set to -1.

Here is the function which reads the bits:

```
 int receiveBit()
{
    while(bit == -1)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }
    fprintf(stderr,"%d",bit);
    int bit2 = bit;
    bit = -1;
    return bit2;
}
```

So the basic run through is this:
After the code has been sent from the receiver to the sender, the sender starts to send kill signals of USR1 and USR2 to the receiver, which should eventually form a binary message.

The receiver is simply waiting at this point, sleeping every second. When it gets interrupted, the handler will set bit to 0 or 1, kicking it out of sleep, printing the bit, and returning it.

If i let the two programs run normally, the reciever just sits in sleep, and the handler is never called (even though I can see the calls being made by the other process.

If i stop the sender, and manually send the Kill signals, i can send one, maybe two signals, both handled properly. any after that, and I get a message printed to the terminal like 'user signal 2'. Which is not something I have in my program, and the program immediately stops.

Any insights as to why my handler isn't being envoked, and why I can't manually send more then one or two signals would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

EDIT:
It seems like people are stumped on this. Are there any debugging tips I could try?

Comment: All I can tell you is that this is a ridiculously inefficient design, and using `pidof` to find a process is not safe or robust. (Imagine someone makes a process with the same name in order to steal the password.) You should be using UNIX domain sockets for this type of communication.

Comment: If you'll note in the first paragraph, I mentioned this is an assignment and not a real-world problem. It is inefficient, and use pidof isn't safe. But I'm not worried about that.

Comment: Is `bit` declared `volatile`?

Comment: bit is simply `int bit = -1;` in the global namespace.

Comment: Some information on your OS would not be amiss

Comment: anything in particular? Its an ubuntu linux install, 10.10 up to date.64bit, nothing particularly outstanding.

Comment: @Blackbinary: the fact that is a Linux system is important. Signals are handled differently among the various Unix-like OSes out there.

Comment: BTW, I cannot replicate the problem. Sure, if I use multiple `kill -USR1 9999` commands at the same time, some signals are missed. But I cannot replicate the program-end issue. It sounds as if you manage to somehow trigger the default SIGUSR2 handler and not your own.

Comment: We'd probably need to see the rest of your program to figure out why you can't send more than a couple signals. And if you can't send them from a program, that program probably has the wrong PID or is running as the wrong user.

Comment: I have verified the PID is the correct one. And they are both run under my user. My signals are all send with a 1 second sleep in between, which should ensure none are missed. I think thkala is right, and the default sigusr2 handler is being called. I don't think i can give out the rest of my program, due to academic restrictions. Are there any chunks that might help you diagnose the problem?

Comment: Most likely, you haven't declared `bit` as `volatile` so the compiler is caching it in a register for your `while` loop and not reloading it.  So even when the value changes, the loop is unaffected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As many have already commented, you shouldn't be doing this with signals at all. When it goes wrong (and it will, like it did) trying to find out what is wrong when undefined behaviour is behind it is hard if not impossible.

Using non async-safe system calls like fprintf inside signal handlers can corrupt the data since fprintf is operating on the same stream. Same with shared variables.

Since you are using linux, signals of the same type will not be blocked, meaning that rapid delivery of the same signal can result in recursive call to the handler. Once a signal is caught, the disposition of the signal is reset to SIG_DFL and needs to be reestablished in the handler again (which can also fail if the signal is delived before it has the change to be reestablished).

That is why you can send a maximum of 1 signal of the same type before the signal gets reset to default and terminated the program with  "user signal xx".

I would recommend you stop tormenting yourself with the code and grab some textbook or a tutorial and try to follow that.

Signal call should also be avoided if it goes. From the man pages:

> The behavior of signal() varies across
>   UNIX versions, and has also varied
>   historically across different versions
>   of Linux.  **Avoid its use**: use
>   sigaction(2) instead.

Comment: I appreciate the honesty. I realize i should be using different functions, and sigaction instead of signal, but this is coursework and I need to confine myself to the guidelines. Is there any way to send signals of the same type in a row? What if i slept longer between signals, would that help? Or should i perhaps use a filler signal i always ignore inbetween every regular signal?

Comment: You've actually given me the answer, I just had to read in more detail. As you said, once a signal is caught, it returns to SIG_DFL, so this means each time I enter my function which will sleep, i simply setup the `signal(SIGUSR1,handler)` to ensure the handler is not SIG_DFL.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things I notice.

- Any shared variables used in signal handlers should be set as `volatile`.
- fprintf() is not a safe function to be used in a signal handler.   Check your man page for `signal()` to get a list of the safe functions.
- also, signal() has a couple different implementations for if a signal handler is reset back to SIG_DFL after being triggered.   Most Unixes suggest to use `sigaction()` to make sure you get the behavior you want.   Or to test you could reset the signal handler inside the handler itself, see if that gives you a different behavior.

Comment: As to why your sender isn't working, I'd write some debug to see if a) your "washingtonPID" variable is what you think it is, and check the return of the kill() routine.   Make sure your're running them both as the same user and neither is setuid to another user.

Comment: I got my sender working, its just the bug with having the default handler grab the signals after 1 or two signals.